# How to set from checkboxes column for filtering in datatable jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I work with jQuery [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) library, and I want to set columns for filtering from checkboxes.

In my case I set columns which need form checkboxes, and if I chose I column, is automatically set 4, but not setting needed columns.

So, if I choose only one column for filtering I got 4, and filters are not being created properly. What could be the reason?

[image]

As seen on the picture above, I set **Station name**, but I didn't get this filter, but the other 4 filters, and I don't understand why?

My code: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ryubts8w/5/)

JS:

```
var idTable = $(".custom-style").attr('id');
var table = $('#' + idTable + '').DataTable();

function addSpliting(val) {
  table.destroy();
  $(idTable).DataTable({
    searchPanes: {
      layout: 'columns-4',
    },
    dom: 'Pfrtip',
    columnDefs: [{
      searchPanes: {
        show: true,
      },
      targets: ['' + val + ''],
    }]
  });
}

function setFilters() {
  $("table thead tr th").each(function(index) {
    var boxes = `<label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="${index}"/>
                        ${$(this).text()}
                    </label>`
    if ($(this).text() != "") $(".checkBoxes").append(boxes);
  });
}

setFilters();

$("#createFilter").on("click", function() {
  var checkedIds = $(".checkbox:checked").map(function() {
    return this.id;
  }).toArray();
  addSpliting(checkedIds.join(", "));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you were pretty close. The problem is that **columnDefs' targets** option only accepts the following:

- An integer (positive or negative)
- A string (class name)
- The string "_all" (all columns)
- An **integers** array

And you're sending a **string** array.

So, you only need to make 2 changes yo your code:

1 - In your "click" event for createFilter, create an integer array instead of string one.

```
$("#createFilter").on("click", function() {

    var columnFilters = [];

    $('.checkbox:checked').each(function () {
        columnFilters.push(parseInt($(this).attr('id')));
    });
    addSpliting(columnFilters);
});
```

2 - In your jQuery DataTable initialization, change this:

```
targets: ['' + val + '']
```

with this:

```
targets: val
```

Here's a working example (I made some modifications to your code):

```js
addSpliting('');

function addSpliting(val) {
  
  if(val != '') {
      
      $("#test1").DataTable({
        destroy: true,
        searchPanes: {
          layout: 'columns-4',
        },
        dom: 'Pfrtip',
        columnDefs: [{
          searchPanes: {
            show: true,
          },
          targets: val
        }]
      });
   }
   else {
      $("#test1").DataTable({
         destroy: true
      });
   }
}

function setFilters() {
  
  $("table thead tr th").each(function(index) {
    
    var boxes = `<label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="${index}"/>
                ${$(this).text()}
                </label>`
    if ($(this).text() != "") $(".checkBoxes").append(boxes);
  });
}

setFilters();

$("#createFilter").on("click", function() {
   var columFilters = [];
  
   $('.checkbox:checked').each(function () {
      columFilters.push(parseInt($(this).attr('id')));
   });
  
   addSpliting(columFilters);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/searchpanes/1.2.0/css/searchPanes.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/css/select.dataTables.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/searchpanes/1.2.0/js/dataTables.searchPanes.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/2.0.3/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>

<div class="content-container">
    <h2 class="head-of-editor">Filtering settings:</h2>
    <div class="checkBoxes"></div>
    <br />
    <a class="button button-clear" id="createFilter" href="#">Create filter</a><br><br>
</div>

<table class="custom-style" id="test1">
   <thead class="table-head">
      <tr>
         <th>Station code</th>
         <th>Station name</th>
         <th>Station type</th>
         <th>Description</th>
         <th>Belongs to production resource(s)</th>
         <th>Main production resource</th>
         <th></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tr>
       <td>a</td>
       <td>b</td>
       <td>c</td>
       <td>a</td>
       <td>b</td>
       <td>c</td>
       <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Thak you for your answer, here in code it's working good, but when i test it i my project and i chosse only one column, in result i got 5 :D

Comment: And i try somehow to fix it, but in result receive same

Comment: Do you think you could try with my code? Also, could you update your jsfiddle with your changes and share the new link, please?

Comment: in jsfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/ryubts8w/7/ it's working normal, yes i try your code, but have the same result

Comment: But in your project are you using your original code, with the suggested modifications, or are you using my code version?

Comment: Probably there's something else in your code messing with the solution. Do you think you can debug your javascript/jQuery code to find the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221931/discussion-between-andrew-and-sagnalrac).

Comment: I found issues, when i change data in table, script stop working https://jsfiddle.net/ryubts8w/8/